# Undefined reference to _aacplusEncOpen

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, cross-platform, aac

Following is the copy of my config.log file->

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=UyTBTTZv

Following is copy of configure file->

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=2c15zppN

Additionally: As of now I am trying to cross-compile ffmpeg on ubuntu,But If I just compile it for linux..The same command doesnt gives any error and executes smoothly and then I am able to get ffmpeg with aacplus support for my linux machine, But why the problem is coming when I am cross compiling it.

Another thing as aacplus is not on by default, If in configuration I dont put any (off by default) library support like if I remove aacplus from it, Then also it goes smoothly.

Help please ASAP

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to already have the *aacplus* library cross-compiled for the target system.